# "Got error creating database manager" - Error in sqoop import query

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

### Scenario:

I am trying to import from sql server into HDFS, but I am getting errors as:

### Error:

```
hadoop@ubuntu:~/sqoop-1.1.0/bin$ ./sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.230.1;username=xxx;password=xxxxx;database=HadoopTest' --table PersonInfo --target-dir /home/hadoop/hadoop-0.21.0/

11/12/10 12:13:20 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Got error creating database manager: java.io.IOException: No manager for connect string: jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.230.1;username=xxx;password=xxxxx;database=HadoopTest
at com.cloudera.sqoop.ConnFactory.getManager(ConnFactory.java:119)
at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool.init(BaseSqoopTool.java:178)
at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.init(ImportTool.java:81)
at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:411)
at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:134)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:69)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:83)
at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:170)
at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:196)
at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:205)
```

### Question:

What is the problem I am not getting?
My Hadoop version : hadoop-0.21.0
Sqoop version : sqoop-1.1.0

Pls suggest me solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Anybody have any hints and/or debugging approaches on this one?  I'm running into an identical problem on sqoop 1.4.3

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong. Use below syntax

```
 ./sqoop import --connect jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.230.1:<PORT_NUMBER>/HadoopTest --username xxx --password xxxxx --table PersonInfo --target-dir /home/hadoop/hadoop-0.21.0/
```

Also make sure that jdbc jasrs should be present in

```
$SQOOP_HOME/lib
```

Answer (score 1):

As strange as it sounds, the use of the single tic ' to enclose your connection string may be causing problems. If you use double quotes " or nothing at all, it may work better for you - at least it does in my environment.

So, instead of

```
./sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.230.1;username=xxx;password=xxxxx;database=HadoopTest' --table PersonInfo --target-dir /home/hadoop/hadoop-0.21.0/
```

try

```
./sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.230.1;username=xxx;password=xxxxx;database=HadoopTest" --table PersonInfo --target-dir /home/hadoop/hadoop-0.21.`0/
```

or

```
./sqoop import --connect jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.230.1;username=xxx;password=xxxxx;database=HadoopTest --table PersonInfo --target-dir /home/hadoop/hadoop-0.21.0/
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: life saver , i cant believe it was blocking me with error 'ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Got error creating database manager: java.io.IOException: No manager for connect string'

Answer (score -2):

You need to specify the Drivermanager

--driver com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver

Comment: I don't think there driver should be specified, Sqoop should be loading the appropriate driver from the connect string jdbc:`sqlserver`://192.168.230.1;user.......... It might be a problem of the SQLServer JDBC Driver not being in the class path.

Comment: I am running into the same problem, though I definitely placed sqljdbc4.jar and slqjdbc.jar in the Sqoop library folder (/usr/lib/sqoop/lib) and ran a similar command only to get the same result.

I've tried using both jars, and one jar each to see if that would help, but no luck